Multiplicative approximation for a negative moment of the binomial distribution
Let $X$ be a binomial random variable with parameters $n,p$.
Define the function
$f(n, p, t) = E\frac{1}{1 + t X},
$
where $t > 0$.

Question: Can we find an elementary function $F(n, p, t)$ such that for some constant $C \in [1, \infty)$, we have
$$
F(n, p, t) \leq f(n, p, t) \leq C \, F(n, p, t),
$$
for all $t > 0$?

Some (perhaps obvious) observations:

Jensen's inequality gives $$f(n, p, t) \geq \frac{1}{1 + t n p},$$
but this is evidently not sharp (described more below).
Consider $p_n = 1/n, t_n = 1$. Then,
$$
(1 - o(1)) \frac{1}{e} = (1 - p_n)^n \leq f(n, p_n, t_n) \leq 1, \quad\qquad (1)
$$
as $n \to \infty$. This shows that (1) isn't sharp: $(1 + t_n n p_n)^{-1} = (1+n)^{-1} \to 0$.
Similarly, we see that if $p \leq \tfrac{1}{2n}$, then
$$
\frac{1}{2} \leq (1-p)^n \leq f(n, p, t) \leq 1.
$$
Thus, we can focus on the case that $p \geq \tfrac{1}{2n}$.


To be clear: You mean $X$ is the number of failures before the $n$th success, so the support of the distribution is ${,0,1,2,3,\ldots,} \text{?}$ (Thus, NOT the number of trials needed to get $n$ successes, which is in ${,n,n+1,n+2,\ldots,}$.)

Your subject line says "negative binomial". By one convention, the negative binomial distribution is the distribution of the number of failures before the first success. It's very different from the binomial distribution, which is bounded.

I think there is confusion, by "negative binomial moment", I mean the "negative moment" of a binomial distribution. Negative moments are of the form $\mathbb{E}_{X \sim P}[(X + a)^{-q}]$, $q > 0$.

The answer is yes, we can find such an elementary function.
Indeed, in the case when $np\le1/2$ we have
\begin{equation}
    f(n,p,t)\ge(1-p)^n\ge(1-p)^{1/(2p)}\ge1/2,
\end{equation}
since $p\le1/2$ in this case, so that
\begin{equation}
    1/2\le f(n,p,t)\le1. 
\end{equation}
Consider now the case $np>1/2$. By Chebyshev's inequality,
\begin{equation}
    P(X\le np/2)\le\frac{np(1-p)}{(np/2-np)^2}\le\frac4{np}. 
\end{equation}
So,
\begin{equation}
    E\frac{1(X\le np/2)}{1+tX}
    =P(X=0)+E\frac{1(1\le X\le np/2)}{1+tX} \\ 
    \le(1-p)^n+\frac4{np}\frac1{1+t}
    \le(1-p)^n+\frac8{1+npt},
\end{equation}
since $np\ge1/2$, and
\begin{equation}
    E\frac{1(X>np/2)}{1+tX}
\le\frac1{1+npt/2}\le\frac2{1+npt},
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}
    E\frac1{1+tX}\le(1-p)^n+\frac{10}{1+npt}.
\end{equation}
On the other hand, as you showed,
\begin{equation}
    E\frac1{1+tX}\ge\max\Big((1-p)^n,\frac1{1+npt}\Big)
    \ge\frac12\Big((1-p)^n+\frac1{1+npt}\Big).
\end{equation}
Thus,
\begin{equation}
    F(n,p,t)\le f(n,p,t)\le CF(n,p,t),
\end{equation}
where $C:=20$ and
\begin{equation}
    F(n,p,t):=
    \left\{
    \begin{alignedat}{2}
    &\frac12&&\text{ if }np\le\frac12, \\ 
    &\frac12\Big((1-p)^n+\frac1{1+npt}\Big) &&\text{ if }np>\frac12. 
    \end{alignedat}
    \right.
\end{equation}

Thanks. The key seemed to be truncation in the upper bound at $np/2$.

@DrewBrady : yes, this reversal is now fixed.
